# How to show that $g:2^M\to 2^\mathbb{N}$ defined by $g(A) = X\cup A$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, ramsey-theory

In [Galvin and Prikry's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272055?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), they inroduce completely Ramsey sets.

Definition  $5$: A set $S\subseteq 2^\mathbb{N}$ is completely Ramsey if $f^{-1}(S)$ is Ramsey for every continuous mapping $f:2^\mathbb{N}\to 2^\mathbb{N}.$

> Question: What is a topology in $2^\mathbb{N}?$

---

As mentioned by @Patrick Stevens below, the authors consider product topology on $2^\mathbb{N}.$

I have another question:

> Question: Suppose that $X$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $M$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{N}.$
>   Define $g:2^M\to 2^\mathbb{N}$ by 
>   $$g(A) = X\cup A.$$
>   How to show that $g$ is continuous?

The function $g$ is defined in the proof of Lemma $7$ of the paper above. 
The authors do not prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map into a product is continuous iff all the compositions with the projections from that product are continuous.

Now $\pi_n \circ g$ is the constant $1$ map for $n \in X$, the identity for all other $n$, so always continuous, so $g$ is too:

Note that $A$ is just identified with $\chi_A: \mathbb{N} \to 2$, so $n \in A$ is just the same as $\pi_n(A)=1$. So $\pi_n(A \cup X)$ is $1$ for all $n \in X$ and all $n \in A$ and $0$ for all $ n \notin A \cup X$. So when  $n \notin X$, $\pi_n(g(A))= \pi_n(A \cup X) = \pi_n(A)$ and for all $n \in X$, $\pi_n(X \cup A) = 1$.

Finiteness of $X$ nor infiniteness of $M$ plays any part.

Comment: It seems that from your argument above, any function $g:2^M\to 2^\mathbb{N}$ is continuous. May I know where is my mistake? In particular, I do not see the definition of $g$ being used anywhere in your argument.

Comment: @Idonknow No, I use the specific definition of $g$ to see the identities on the projections. There are many discontinuous maps from $2^M$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How do you obtain that $\pi_n\circ g$ is the constant function $1$?

Comment: @Idonknow I expanded the argument. $X$ is always a subset of $g(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

As the paper says in the first paragraph, it's the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

Comment: I have modified my question. In particular, how do we show that a map $g:2^M\to 2^\mathbb{N}$ is continuous where $M$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{N}?$